# Get range from cell and apply to getRangeList

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a code that changes the other checkboxes in the range written in the cell with one check box.

It works, but I want to use "getRangeList" to make all the check boxes change at once, but I don't know how to bring in the ranges written in column B.

(If change the range you wrote in column B, it'll be applied to the code.)

sheet1

[image]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var cell = sht.getActiveCell();
var rng = cell.getA1Notation();

if(rng=="E2"){
  if(cell.getValue()==false){
    cell.setValue(true);
    for(var i=4; i<=100; i++){
      var tmp = sht.getRange("B"+i).getValue();
      if(tmp!=""){
        sht.getRange( tmp ).setValue(false);
        
      }
    }
  }
}
//var list = ['F4:H4','F5:G5','F6','F7:I7'];
//sht.getRangeList(list).setValue(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to uncheck the checkboxes when `onEdit` is run.
- You want to retrieve the values from the cells `B4:B` as the range list, and want to uncheck the checkboxes.
- When you change the cells `B4:B`, you want to also reflect to the checkbox.
- From your script, also I understood as follows.

  - You want to run the script as the simple trigger for the cells. And also, you want to directly run the function with the script editor.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Clear the data validations of the cells `F4:I`.
  2. Retrieve the values from the cells `B4:B` as the range list.
  3. Insert the checkboxes.
  4. Uncheck the checkboxes.

When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var cell = sht.getActiveCell();
  var rng = cell.getA1Notation();
  if(rng=="E2"){
    if(cell.getValue()==false){
      cell.setValue(true);
      for(var i=4; i<=100; i++){
        var tmp = sht.getRange("B"+i).getValue();
        if(tmp!=""){
          sht.getRange( tmp ).setValue(false);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // I added below script.
  if (cell.getColumn() == 2 && cell.getRow() >= 4) {
    // 1. Clear the data validations of the cells `F4:I`.
    sht.getRange("F4:I" + sht.getLastRow()).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    // 2. Retrieve the values from the cells `B4:B` as the range list.
    var a1Notations = sht.getRange("B4:B" + sht.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(String);
    
    // 3. Insert the checkboxes.
    var rangeList = sht.getRangeList(a1Notations);
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
    rangeList.getRanges().forEach(r => r.setDataValidation(rule));

    // 4. Uncheck the checkboxes.
    rangeList.uncheck();
  }
}
```

- When you use this script, please add or modify the a1Notation in the cells `B4:B`. By this, the script retrieves the a1Notations as the range list, and the checkboxes are cleared and inserted using the a1Notations, and the checkboxes are unchecked.
- In the current modified script, from your sample image, `F4:I` is used as the range of checkboxes. When this is different from your actual situation, please modify it.

#### Note:

- As an additional information, when the event object `e` of `onEdit(e)` is used, the process cost can be reduced a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)

#### References:

- [clearDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#cleardatavalidations)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [setDataValidation(rule)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule)

Answer (score 1):

- Get the `Range` B4:B from `Sheet` and filter out empty rows
- Get the `RangeList` and `uncheck()` it.

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  const editedRg = e.range;
  const sht = editedRg.getSheet();
  const editedRgA1 = editedRg.getA1Notation();
  if (editedRgA1 === 'E2') {
    if (!editedRg.isChecked()) {
      sht
        .getRangeList(
          sht
            .getRange(1 + 3, 2, sht.getLastRow() - 3)
            .getValues()
            .flat()
            .filter(String)
        )
        .uncheck();
      editedRg.check();
    }
  }
}
```